# HTML5 Audio Player - Autoplay Next Class Instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using UbaPlayer, which is a jQuery HTML5 audio player with Flash fallback. Currently, it just stops after the particular song that is cued is finished.

I would like for it to autoplay the next "audiobutton" class that is chronologically listed.

@Winner_joiner has managed to edit line 190 to move to the next song in the `<ul>` but after the last song of that `<ul>` finishes, it goes to the first instance of `<ul class=controls>`, whereas I would like for it to continue to the NEXT chronological instance of `<ul>`.

I have content between some songs, so I have to break the `<ul>` and start another for other songs.

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.ubaplayer.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
            codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}]
            });

    });
    jQuery('a[rel=vidbox]').click(function () {

        if (jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("playing") === true) {
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("pause");
            }
        return false;
    });
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ubaPlayer"></div>
    <ul class="controls">
        <li><a class="audioButton" href="mp3/dontthinktwice.mp3">
        Don't Think Twice (Bob Dylan)</a></li>
        <li><a class="audioButton" href="mp3/livingforthecity.mp3">
        Living for the City (Stevie Wonder)</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- More content and stuff here-->

    <ul class="controls">
        <li><a class="audioButton" href="mp3/anothersong.mp3">
        Another Song</a></li>
        <li><a class="audioButton" href="mp3/anothersong2.mp3">
        Another Song 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**Audio Player JavaScript:**

```
(function($) {
var defaults = {
    audioButtonClass: "audioButton",
    autoPlay: null,
    codecs: [{
        name: "OGG",
        codec: 'audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'
    }, {
        name: "MP3",
        codec: 'audio/mpeg'
    }],
    continuous: false,
    extension: null,
    flashAudioPlayerPath: "libs/swf/player.swf",
    flashExtension: ".mp3",
    flashObjectID: "audioPlayer",
    loadingClass: "loading",
    loop: false,
    playerContainer: "player",
    playingClass: "playing",
    swfobjectPath: "libs/swfobject/swfobject.js",
    volume: 1
},
    currentTrack, isPlaying = false,
    isFlash = false,
    audio, $buttons, $tgt, $el, playTrack, resumeTrack, pauseTrack, methods = {
        play: function(element) {
            $tgt = element;
            currentTrack = _methods.getFileNameWithoutExtension($tgt.attr("href"));
            isPlaying = true;
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);

            if (isFlash) {
                if (audio) {
                    _methods.removeListeners(window);
                }
                audio = document.getElementById(defaults.flashObjectID);
                _methods.addListeners(window);
                audio.playFlash(currentTrack + defaults.extension);
            } else {
                if (audio) {
                    audio.pause();
                    _methods.removeListeners(audio);
                }
                audio = new Audio("");
                _methods.addListeners(audio);
                audio.id = "audio";
                audio.loop = defaults.loop ? "loop" : "";
                audio.volume = defaults.volume;
                audio.src = currentTrack + defaults.extension;
                audio.play();
            }
        },

        pause: function() {
            if (isFlash) {
                audio.pauseFlash();
            } else {
                audio.pause();
            }

            $tgt.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);
            isPlaying = false;
        },

        resume: function() {
            if (isFlash) {
                audio.playFlash();
            } else {
                audio.play();
            }
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.playingClass);
            isPlaying = true;
        },

        playing: function() {
            return isPlaying;
        }
    },

    _methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var types;

            //set defaults
            $.extend(defaults, options);
            $el = this;

            //listen for clicks on the controls
            $(".controls").bind("click", function(event) {
                _methods.updateTrackState(event);
                return false;
            });
            $buttons = $("." + defaults.audioButtonClass);

            types = defaults.codecs;
            for (var i = 0, ilen = types.length; i < ilen; i++) {
                var type = types[i];
                if (_methods.canPlay(type)) {
                    defaults.extension = [".", type.name.toLowerCase()].join("");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!defaults.extension || isFlash) {
                isFlash = true;
                defaults.extension = defaults.flashExtension;
            }

            if (isFlash) {
                $el.html("<div id='" + defaults.playerContainer + "'/>");
                $.getScript(defaults.swfobjectPath, function() {
                    swfobject.embedSWF(defaults.flashAudioPlayerPath, defaults.playerContainer, "0", "0", "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", false, false, {
                        id: defaults.flashObjectID
                    }, _methods.swfLoaded);
                });
            } else {
                if (defaults.autoPlay) {
                    methods.play(defaults.autoPlay);
                }
            }
        },

        updateTrackState: function(evt) {
            $tgt = $(evt.target);
            if (!$tgt.hasClass("audioButton")) {
                return;
            }
            if (!audio || (audio && currentTrack !== _methods.getFileNameWithoutExtension($tgt.attr("href")))) {
                methods.play($tgt);
            } else if (!isPlaying) {
                methods.resume();
            } else {
                methods.pause();
            }
        },

        addListeners: function(elem) {
            $(elem).bind({
                "canplay": _methods.onLoaded,
                "error": _methods.onError,
                "ended": _methods.onEnded
            });
        },

        removeListeners: function(elem) {
            $(elem).unbind({
                "canplay": _methods.onLoaded,
                "error": _methods.onError,
                "ended": _methods.onEnded
            });
        },

        onLoaded: function() {
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.playingClass);

            audio.play();
        },

        onError: function() {
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            if (isFlash) {
                _methods.removeListeners(window);
            } else {
                _methods.removeListeners(audio);
            }
        },

        onEnded: function() {
            isPlaying = false;
            $tgt.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);
            currentTrack = "";
            if (isFlash) {
                _methods.removeListeners(window);
            } else {
                _methods.removeListeners(audio);
            }

            if (defaults.continuous) {
                var $next = $tgt.next().length ? $tgt.next() : $(defaults.audioButtonClass).eq(0);
                methods.play($next);
            }

        },

        canPlay: function(type) {
            if (!document.createElement("audio").canPlayType) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return document.createElement("audio").canPlayType(type.codec).match(/maybe|probably/i) ? true : false;
            }
        },

        swfLoaded: function() {
            if (defaults.autoPlay) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    methods.play(defaults.autoPlay);
                }, 500);
            }
        },

        getFileNameWithoutExtension: function(fileName) {
            //this function take a full file name and returns an extensionless file name
            //ex. entering foo.mp3 returns foo
            //ex. entering foo returns foo (no change)
            var fileNamePieces = fileName.split('.');
            fileNamePieces.pop();
            return fileNamePieces.join(".");
        }
    };

$.fn.ubaPlayer = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
        return _methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.ubaPlayer");
    }
};})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've noticed your original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308030/how-can-i-get-this-jquery-audio-player-to-advance-to-the-next-player-when-finish. I'll look into this when I get home later today. Please don't post duplicate questions :)

Comment: @darshanags Any luck?

Comment: Is my answer ... not good enough? If so please, help me to help you and if it solves the issue please accept my answer THX :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the lib (or a not documented feature).

it works **only** if the audiobuttons are direct siblings (prove in line 190 in jquery.ubaplayer.js)

```
var $next = $tgt.next().length ? $tgt.next() : $(defaults.audioButtonClass).eq(0);
// a other unrelated bug in the same line is ... $(defaults.audioButtonClass) should be $("." + defaults.audioButtonClass) or so
```

with other words if your HTML looks like this( with *continuous:true*):

```
 <div class="controls"> <!-- THIS IS NOW AN DIV NOT UL-->
     <!-- NO LI'S since the links have to be direkt siblings-->
        <a class="audioButton" href="mp3/dontthinktwice.mp3">
        Don't Think Twice (Bob Dylan)</a>
        <a class="audioButton" href="mp3/livingforthecity.mp3">
        Living for the City (Stevie Wonder)</a>
 </div>
```

it works(with chrome 25+)

i hope this helps.

**Update 1:**

if you want to use **your HTML** you would have to update the line 190 in the File jquery.ubaplayer.js to

```
var $next = $tgt.parent().next().length>0 && $tgt.parent().next().children().length>0?$tgt.parent().next().children().eq(0):$("."+defaults.audioButtonClass).eq(0);
// Code could/should be cleaned up a bit
```

This code gets the parent of the a-Tag = the li-Tag, checks if it has a sibling, if so gets the correct audio href.

**Warning i just checked if the code runs, for your question, i donno if it causes problems in other usage scenarios. (btw. i would just change the HTML and leave the LIB AS-IS, so that if an update come or so there are no break changes)**

**Update 2:**

Code to Call Ubaplayer with autoplay

```
 jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
        codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}],
        autoPlay:$(".audioButton").eq(0)
 });
```

Comment: I added "."+ to 190 and then set continuous to "true"... now, it goes back to the first song, no matter which one is currently playing. I have about 20 on that page, but it always returns back to the first song. Would you know why?

Comment: The Problem is **not the bug** in line 190. The problem is that you must remove the ul-tag and the li-tags. look at the HTML code in the answer, this HTML-Code works. if you want it to work with your HTML you would have to modify the line 190 some more...

Comment: Hmm... using something like an autoplay function?

Comment: I dont understand do you want to use autoplay? if so you have to add the setting `autoPlay:$(".audioButton").eq(0)` in your ubaplayer. I hope no everything is up and running. :)

Comment: p.s.: i updated my answer also, so all the information is, in one place. :)

Comment: The problem with them being direct siblings is that the CSS is using the `<li>` to style them. If I change to a div, then they wouldn't be styled correctly and the whole "animation" wouldn't work. Yes?

Comment: If you look at the last part of my answer(**Update 1 - 2**), you can keep the HTML as you have it, you would only have to fix the the ubaplayer Lib...

Comment: I finally got a chance to check this. It works while continuing down the `<ul>` HOWEVER once I start another, it goes to the beginning of the first `<ul>`.

Comment: By the way, I have other content listed in between `<ul>` controls, so the goal is to continue to the next chronologically listed `<ul>` without it going back to the first listed.

Comment: Hey Man, i answered your intial question(and any with the given code in your question), i even digged into the lib, and fixed a bug in the lib (offert two solutions). I sorry, if you need more support with the library, please contact the developer(or get a better audio lib). If you dont think i deserve the **accepted answer**, thats fine its your call... but here my support must end. Good Luck